# What is the best paper size for thesis, which should be printed out as a book?

Tags: typography, geometry, paper

recently I have been preparing to write my thesis in latex. Which is the best paper size according to your point of view for a thesis, that should be later printed as a book? If possible please provide some typography views.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be useful to know which paper formats are customary where you are: letter (mainly US)? DIN, f.i. A4?

Comment: What size you use for your thesis, should be immaterial for a published book, as publishers might have different opinions to that of the University requirements. Best look at published books in your field available as pdfs and check the sizes in the properties panel. In general personally I prefer A4 for a thesis. Also consult a publisher early. Many humanities and science fields produce books in series, and size will be determined by that.

Comment: Indeed make sure to check if there are any requirements (or maybe strong traditions) from your university about the format of the thesis itself. Of course these must be followed first in order to defend the PhD. Then if you want to publish it separately after the defense then you can change the size if you like. The promise of LaTeX is that content is separated from formatting, so in theory you only need to change one documentclass or geometry option somewhere and the whole thesis will nicely reflow and automatically look good in the new format.

Comment: (that will not happen in practise but hopefully the required changes will indeed be minimal, especially when you adhere to the LaTeX philosophy while writing and not try to force too much manual formatting on individual pages).

Comment: @marquinho Hi, thank you for your reply. I am in Germany and the paper formats that are usually used are DIN like A4/5 as far as i know.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I am writing my phd thesis now. And for my master thesis I also did use A4 size. But I also saw someone printed their phd thesis in A5 size. So I wonder if there are some advantages choosing that smaller size.

Comment: @Marijn there is indeed some kind of latex class file based on KOMA script from my university and also available in CTAN. But personally I don't like the style very much and my faculty doesn't force to use that specific style. So I choose now the "classicthesis" provided by André Miede and Ivo Pletikosić, which is really well structured as I see. And based on that package I also make some adjustments to generate my own style. I may ask my supervisor for some advice. But thank you for reply.

Comment: @RonghuaXu I'm in The Netherlands (hi neighbor!) and there almost all PhD theses are printed on A5. It might be more readable for such a long text or easier to handle physically (note that most 'normal' books, like novels, also have this kind of size) but I think the main reason for choosing the size is just that everybody else does it :)

Comment: @Marijn Hi neighbor:) that's an interesting point. I may consider to be one of them :)